# Work around for lack of sqlProjection support within criteria builder?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2803 concerns lack of support for sqlProjection. It was closed as a duplicate and supposedly fixed in Grails v1.2. But the "duplicate" issue concerned sqlRestriction and I do not believe sqlProjection has been implemented as of Grails v1.3.2 at least.

Are there any workarounds to use sqlProjection within a critera? For example,

```
def results = Report.createCriteria() list {
            projections {
                sum('correctResponses')
                sum('allResponses')

                sqlProjection("(sum(correct_responses) / sum(all_responses))", ["grade"] as String[], [Hibernate.INTEGER] as Type[])
                groupProperty('name')
            }
            and {
                if (startDate)
                    ge("date", startDate)

                if (endDate)
                    lt("date", endDate + 1) //add one day so search is inclusive of end date

                'in' ("id", ids)
            }
            order(orderColumn ?: 'name', orderDirection ?: 'asc')
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and found the solution in the answer to another question.

You can work around this issue by using the addProjectionToList() method. Take a look at 'Option 2' in the following answer for an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7652787

The criteria DSL for this particular example would be as follows:

```
def results = Report.createCriteria().list {
    projections {
        sum('correctResponses')
        sum('allResponses')

        addProjectionToList(Projections.sqlProjection(
            '(sum(correct_responses) / sum(all_responses)) as grade',
            ['grade'] as String[],
            [Hibernate.INTEGER] as Type[]
        ), 'sumProjection')
        groupProperty('name')
    }
    and {
        if (startDate)
            ge("date", startDate)

        if (endDate)
            lt("date", endDate + 1) //add one day so search is inclusive of end date

        'in'("id", ids)
    }
    order(orderColumn ?: 'name', orderDirection ?: 'asc')
}
```