# Grails projection on arithmetic expression with executeQuery()?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I need to get a sum of all items sold per order per store. I am running a sum() on expression using executeQuery(). It works fine as shown below but I wanted to know if there is a better, groovier way to do it.

```
StoreService {
  static transactional = false

  def getTotalOrders(def store) {
    return Store.executeQuery("select sum(a.soldQuantity * a.soldPrice) as total 
             from OrderItem a inner join a.order b inner join b.store c 
             where c= :store", [store: store]).get(0)
  }
}

Store {
  transient storeService

  def getTotalSales() {
    storeService.getTotalSales()
  }

  static hasMany = [items: Item]
  // no hasMany to Order
}

Item {
  static belongsTo = [store: Store]
  // no hasMany to OrderItem
}


Order {
  static hasMany = [orderItems: OrderItem]
  static belongsTo = [store: Store]
}


OrderItem {

  BigDecimal soldPrice
  Integer soldQuantity

  static belongsTo = [order: Order, item: Item]

}
```

I think withCriteria() would be easier to read but I couldn't figure out how to do it with expressions within sum() wouldn't take for obvious reasons.

```
projections {
  sum("soldPrice * soldQuantity")
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two options you can go with.

**Option 1**

You can add a formula mapping to your domain class then query it directly.

```
OrderItem {
  BigDecimal soldPrice
  Integer soldQuantity
  BigDecimal totalPrice

  static mapping = {
    totalPrice formula: "sold_price * sold_quantity"
  }

  static belongsTo = [order: Order, item: Item]

}
```

Now your criteria query can just contain

```
projections {
    sum("totalPrice")
}
```

Not only that but you can query it with dynamic finders `OrderItem.findAllByTotalPriceGreaterThan(20.00)` as well as simple access `println "The final price is ${orderInstance.totalPrice}`. We find this really nifty however there are times when you would want to get totalPrice before the OrderItem has been persisted so we usually write a simple(Not DRY) getter

```
BigDecimal getTotalPrice() {
    totalPrice ?: (soldPrice && soldQuantity) ? soldPrice * soldQuantity : null
}
```

But you only need this sort of thing if you require totalPrice before it has been persisted.

**Option 2**

Before formula mappings we used to drop down to the Hibernate Criteria API and use a sqlProjection Projection as part of our criteria query.

```
projections {
    addProjectionToList(Projections.sqlProjection(
            "sum(sold_price * sold_quantity) as totalPrice",
            ["totalPrice"] as String[], 
            [Hibernate.LONG] as Type[],
        ), "sumProjection")
 }
```

**Note**

I think it is important to note that in both the formula and the sql projection, use the column names in the database and your database specific sum syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. We are already using getTotalPrice() as a transient and adding totalPrice mapping as a formula is a great suggestion, will do.

Comment: Can you order based on the mappings?

Answer (score 2):

As of Grails 2.2, SQL projections are supported without having to drop down to the Hibernate Criteria API.  Note that a formula mapping may still be more desirable, but with this you can directly implement the sum('soldPrice * soldQuantity') style projection as per your question.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#criteria

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to add a transient [derived property](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.2.11%20Derived%20Properties) `total` to `OrderItem` and use `sum()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try SQL Projection

```
projections {
  sqlProjection 'sum("soldPrice * soldQuantity") as total', 'total', StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE
}
```

For farther details
http://docs.grails.org/2.5.6/guide/GORM.html#criteria